# JQuery Auto Suggest Serverside

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Coming up with a server side JQuery plug-in is proving to be a bit brutal.  I have looked around for one but they work off static information.  Does anyone have a good free server-side Auto suggest for JQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean you want a client-side JQuery autocomplete control that queries a server-side database for the data?  If so, [this tutorial](http://nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/) covers exactly that, with a [live demo here](http://res.nodstrum.com/autoComplete/index.htm).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at these:

1. [pengoworks](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm)
2. [ajax daddy](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html)
3. [jQuery Site](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jq-autocomplete)

Example:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete("myWebService.ashx");
```

You would then create the myWebService.ashx that your jQuery would call to get the data from, typically in JSON format...

Take a look at this question here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305994/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net).

Answer (score 5):

Autocomplete is now built into jQuery UI:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I searched earlier but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There's also an [autocomplete jQuery plug-in](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) by Drew Wilson that's lightweight but has some really nice additional features compared to the jQuery UI one.

Might be of interest.

I have no affiliation with Drew.

Answer (score 0):

Newborn *Remote-Auto-Search-Suggest* [BBSearch](http://fguillen.github.com/BBSearch/)

*Disclaimer: I'm the author*.