# What is JQuery's equivalent of scriptaculous/prototype's auto-complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous, autosuggest

Prototype/scriptaculous can do an easy autosuggest in the input box.
It's pretty much built in.

How can I do that with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery plugin: Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something that will get the info from the server then you can look at this question:
[JQuery Auto Suggest Serverside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967199/jquery-auto-suggest-serverside)

It is risky to have it done on the client, as you need to pass all the data to the client, then you just search as the user types, so I doubt that is what you expect.