# jQuery Tag Editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

Is there any open source tag editor for jQuery that works like the tag editor in stack overflow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up JQuery autocomplete like Stackoverflow's tags input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/how-can-i-set-up-jquery-autocomplete-like-stackoverflows-tags-input-field)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have been looking at a bunch of options. None of them seemed to fit exactly what I was looking for. Here are are least some of the things I found.

- [Tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/)
- [Tagit](http://webspirited.com/tagit/docs.html)
- [Xoxco](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/)
- [Tagedit](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/)
- [Widen Tagit](http://widen.github.com/jQuery-Tagit/)

Hope it helps

```
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Toolkit             |Tag-it|Tagit|Xoxco|Tagedit|Widen|
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Setting tags        |-     |+    |+    |?      |+    |
|programmatically    |      |     |     |       |     |
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Getting tags out as |+     |+    |-    |?      |+    |
|an array            |      |     |     |       |     |
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Editting existing   |-     |-    |-    |+      |+    |
|tags                |      |     |     |       |     |
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Tab / cursor        |-     |-    |-    |-      |-    |
|selecting existing  |      |     |     |       |     |
|tags                |      |     |     |       |     |
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Sorting tags        |-     |+    |-    |+      |+    |
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Placeholder text    |-     |-    |+    |-      |-    |
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
|Supporting comma    |-     |+    |-    |+      |+    |
|inside tags         |      |     |     |       |     |
+--------------------+------+-----+-----+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Hi Wilfried, I've just released a plugin that probably beats all of the listed ones. There would be a "+" on each row. I'd be happy if you'd take a look and - if you concur - include it in your answer:
http://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html
Looking forward to your feedback.

Comment: @wilfred-springer anything else like Simon Steinberger's that you would now like to add to the list?

Answer (score 11):

This library is really nice:

https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input

Supports autocomplete too, and it plays well with jQuery UI (using it inside a jQuery UI Dialog at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

The tag editor uses an "[Autocomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete)" feature - [jQueryUI recently added this in version 1.8](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete).  It appears to be based on [the classic jQuery autocomplete plugin by Jörn Zaefferer](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) (I haven't compared the source, but the API seems pretty similar).

Comment: True - I would also like to see one that does per-word matching.  I've done some searches but they came up empty.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this: http://blog.crazybeavers.se/wp-content/Demos/jquery.tag.editor

Comment: That link doesn't work for me, but this one does: http://blog.crazybeavers.se/wp-content/Demos/jquery.tag.editor/

Answer (score 3):

[Tag Editor Field using jQuery similar to StackOverflow](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2011/09/09/Tag-Editor-Field-using-jQuery-similar-to-StackOverflow.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Read This too:

> [JQuery Auto Suggest Serverside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967199/jquery-auto-suggest-serverside)

btw the best autosuggest for me is the one from www.brandspankingnew.net

> http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2006/08/ajax_auto-suggest_auto-complete.html

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is true for original poster, but for people who want end users to pick from a *fixed* universe of tags via autocomplete (without being able to add their own new tags), this is a potentially slick jQuery plugin:

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: Note, set the AllowFreeTagging boolean config to true and you get to insert new tags as well. It's undocumented, but you can search the git repo for some details  https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/367

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Tagedit](http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/) it has autocomplete, edit existing tags, enter your own tags with a simple configurable API that you would expect in such as plugin

Answer (score 0):

try with http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/ it has also some good features.