# How to create input-tags style just like this website's askquestion tags block?

Tags: html, css, tags

I wan't to create a form with input .

U can enter what u want in it ,and u also can easy remove it.

Just like stackoverflow's ask question tags block.

what should i do!

[what should i do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPqtX.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Tag Editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531255/jquery-tag-editor)

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Comment: "what should i do " -> click on first comment link and read it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.
https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

Here is examples: http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html

And here is the homepage : http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

........................................

Alternatively you can use this : http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/

Here is examples : http://webspirited.com/tagit/