# Can Google Places Autocomplete be using in a Tag Editor field?

Tags: json, jquery-autocomplete, google-places

We'd like to be able to enter many addresses in one field, saving entered ones as tags (as [these libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531255/jquery-tag-editor) do) and using Google Places Autocomplete as a new one is typed.

Has anyone achieved this already?

I've tried using tagedit with the following startup with no luck:

```
$('input.tag').tagedit({autocompleteURL:"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=",breakKeyCodes: [ 186]});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. I was able to accomplish this using Places AutoCompleteService and tagit (http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/).
Here's the basic setup

```
        var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        $('#myInputField').tagit(
                {
                    autocomplete: {source: function (req, callback) {
                        if (req.term.length > 2) {
                            service.getQueryPredictions({ input: req.term}, function (predictions, status) {
                                callback($.map(predictions, function ($val, $i) {
                                    return $val.description;
                                }));
                            });
                        }
                    }}
                    allowSpaces:true,
                    singleFieldDelimiter:'|'
                }
        );
```