# Set caret position in non-editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I'm trying to make a box to select different options and proccess its information.
I want to get a result like this:

[image: box]

It's a jQuery plugin called [jQuery Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags)

I was seeing that it isn't contentEditable div, it has only a tabindex with "-1" value to can focus this element.

I was looking for an answer but I found only about contentEditable elements or inputs or textareas

I want to set the caret position to the end after it gets focused.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ivaj/T79rW/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selector').on('focus', function () {
        //..some code to pos the caret
    });
});
```

I was thinking on something like that

Comment: Well it is sort of hard to add a cursor when you cannot actually edit it....

Comment: Ohh, yes, I was thinking the same, I'd like to just remove each block of "li" tags but when I make the div "contentEditable" and I press the backspace it removes letter by letter and not the entire "li". But first at all I don't know how jQuery Select2 set the caret position if the div boxes aren't contentEditable ? thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You know there are libraries that already do this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531255/jquery-tag-editor

Comment: Oh, now I have more ideas to do that :) thank you!

Comment: Why would you want a cursor, when the whole thing looks like a very nice, clickable element?

Comment: It's because I want a search form to add tags with preload data but I'll fixt it putting an input at the end :D