# How to give a C# handler file as a url to jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, composite-controls

I am creating a custom control in asp.net . In the control itself i have to call the url for getting results for autocomplete. But both .aspx, .ashx file format are not supported by class library. Is there any other format for substituite of the above to redirect inside the class library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

> [jQuery Autocomplete and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305994/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net)

And the jQuery autocomplete works with an ashx (I use it). Maybe it would be usefull if you post some code to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with any type of downloadable asp file (aspx, ashx and asmx too) as long as they return data in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ASHX is an HTTP handler; you can create a handler using IHttpHandler, register this in the  section, and use this to process requests.

HTH.