# How to do auto complete in city textbox

Tags: jquery

I have state and city dropdown list in an ASP.NET 3.5 application. However, I want city as a textbox, and upon me typing in it, autocomplete mode should occur.

I want to implement it through jQuery, so can anyone please send me the code for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

`$("#yourtextboxID").autocomplete({source: ["Los Angeles","Las Vegas","Madrid"]});`

Comment: Thanks Alexander 
But tell me one thing how to bind source .
This source in C# file which contain id and values of cities .

Comment: $("#yourtextboxID").autocomplete(
{

source: [{value:1, label: "Los Angeles"},{value:2, label: "Las Vegas"},{value:3, label: "Madrid"}],

select: function(event, ui) {

$('#yourtextboxID').val(ui.item.label);

$('#yourhiddenfieldID').val(ui.item.value);

return false;

}

});

Comment: Thanks for you help.
But i want to give source from c# function to in source there sould be function 
how can i call function in source :

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to use the [jQuery Autocompleye plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete).

If that doesn't tickle your fancy, try checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188442/whats-a-good-ajax-autocomplete-plugin-for-jquery). If you're having problems specifically with Asp.NET in conjunction with jQuery and AJAX, it looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305994/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net) may be of use as well.