# JQuery UI Autocomplete and Generic Handler (ashx) - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete, httphandler

I'm trying to use the JQuery Autocomplete, but I guess I am having trouble getting the format it expects from my handler.

Here is what the handler does.  This was in another SO question....

```
 context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
 var companies = GetCompanies(); //This returns a list of companies (List<string>)

 foreach (var comp in companies)
 {
     context.Response.Write(comp + Environment.NewLine);
 }
```

This doesn't work.  It is definately getting called and it is returning what I would expect this code to return.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response needs to be in JSON format.  See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete where it discusses using a String that specifies a URL.

Comment: So then I am assuming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305994/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net is using a plugin instead of the JQuery UI... OOps

Answer (score 6):

It needs to be in JSON format indeed, here a sample of the general outline I used before:

```
    class AutoCompleteEntry
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    private void GetAutoCompleteTerms()
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        //evaluate input parameters of jquery request here

         List<AutoCompleteEntry> autoCompleteList= new List<AutoCompleteEntry>();
        //populate List of AutocompleteEntry here accordingly

        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jsSerializer.Serialize(autoCompleteList);
        Response.Write(json);
        Response.End();
    }
```