# AutoComplete in Webforms [bsnautosuggest and jqueryautocomplete]

Tags: asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

I want to know which one is the best way to implement autocomplete in aspx forms using jquery?
 What is the difference between using bsn.autosuggest and jquery autocomplete.If possible pls explain
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305994/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net) on StackOverflow?

Comment: @Shog9 I want to know which one is the best way to implement autocomplete? What is the differenc between using bsn.autosuggest and jquery autocomplete.If possible pls explain.

Answer (score 1):

The [UI Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) should help you out. Is there something specific you're trying to hook the auto-complete to? The examples in the documentation give a pretty good explanation for several use cases to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

I think themeing is the greatest advantage with Jquery UI auto complete.

you can get the advantages of Jquery UI auto complete [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)