# Showing real time result in textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I'm developing a website (ASP.net) which involves users typing in a textbox to search. I want to display result in the textbox as they are typing the keywords (just like when we are searching on Google).

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use combobox  instead of Textbox

Comment: Try Ajax Control Toolkit AutoComplete Text box... here the code is : http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_simple.ashx

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is called **autocomplete** and since you are working on asp.net the most easy direct solution is the use of asp.net ajax control toolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

How ever if you use some other javascript helper library, like jQuery, you can find a lot more examples, one of them : [jQuery Autocomplete and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305994/jquery-autocomplete-and-asp-net)

Also if you search for "autocomplete asp.net" you find more examples, some of them:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_Simple.ashx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201099/AutoComplete-With-DataBase-and-AjaxControlToolkit